# Refreshing dojo datagrid not always working in FF9

Tags: datagrid, dojo, firefox-9

I have a Dojo EnhancedGrid connected to a JsonRestStore. `clearOnClose` is set to true on the store. Usually I refresh it by doing

```
grid.store.close();
grid.setStore(window.store.tester);
```

Or

```
grid._refresh();
```

This works fine in every browser, but not in the newest version of FF9 (in version 4,5 it worked well).
In FF9, nothing happens at all and the store is not cleared or refreshed. Oddly, it does work after trying a few times and debugging it. But when I clear the browser history and cache and then try to refresh, it never works.

Does anyone have a clue what happens? What could be different in FF9 and is there another way to definately refresh the grid?

Comment: I tracked the issue down: basically the  `_clearData()` method of the DataGrid class is not working (grid is not cleared and so newly loaded data cannot be inserted). I am using Dojo 1.6. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. I found the reason now, it was some screwed hashtag logic which caused the grid to be refreshed twice at a time in Firefox. I corrected it and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Are You using Firebug. If yes, then try switching it off and reloading the page. Dojo grids don't get along very well with Firebug.